# Always call component did update on construct?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I've been finding myself writing code that looks like this:

```
class MyComponent extends Component {

   constructor(props) {
       super(props); 

       const {foo, bar, fetchFoo, fetchBar} = props; 

       if (!foo) {
         fetchFoo(); 
       }

       if (foo && foo.someCondition) {
         fetchBar(); 
       }
   }


   componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
      if(prevProps.foo != this.props.foo && this.pros.foo.someCondition) {
         this.props.fetchBar(); 
      }
   }

}


const mapStateToProps = (
  state,
) => {
  return {
    foo: state.foo, 
    bar: state.bar
  };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
  return {
    fetchFoo: () => dispatch(fetchFoo()), 
    fetchBar: () => dispatch(fetchBar()), 
    },
  };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(MyComponent);
```

Where my component has two items bound from the redux state - `foo` and `bar`. But my component needs `foo` first, as in certain conditions of `foo` I might redirect to another place (ie. if they have already completed the form).

But I don't know whether either item exists in the redux state or not.

So I test for `foo`'s existence and condition on both `construct` and `componentDidUpdate`. This makes for duplicated code, and makes it more difficult to test.

Is tidy way to get the constructor to just execute the `componentDidUpdate` functionality? Just call `this.componentDidUpdate({})` in the constructor?

Or otherwise another tidy way of doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no reason why a stateless functional component wouldn't work here.

```
const MyComponent = ({foo, bar, fetchFoo, fetchBar}) => {
       if (!foo) {
         fetchFoo(); 
       }

       if (foo && foo.someCondition) {
         fetchBar(); 
       }

       return (<Fragment> {JSON.stringify(foo) + JSON.stingify(bar)}</Fragment>); 
};
```

Now - if you especially need some state - then you could use [React Hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html) to introduce some.

Answer (score 1):

Extract it into another function and call that function from both the `constructor` and `componentDidUpdate`